# Looking for a better way to convert text to time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a better way to convert text entered like 1:27:00 PM EST into an actual time format.  I looked for a way to directly convert this to an actual time without success.  All of the posts I saw involved converting the decimal Excel uses for time calculation.  After an hour or so searching in vain, I worked out the following brute force method:

```
=((VALUE(LEFT(tbl_Report[Actual End Time],FIND(":",tbl_Report[Actual End Time])-1))/24)+(VALUE(MID(tbl_Report[Actual End Time],FIND(":",tbl_Report[Actual End Time])+1,2))/60)/24+IF(AND(MID(tbl_Report[Actual End Time],FIND(" ", tbl_Report[Actual Start Time])+1,2)="PM",VALUE(LEFT(tbl_Report[Actual End Time],FIND(":",tbl_Report[Actual End Time])-1))<>0.5),0.5))
```

There has to be a better way and I'm hoping one of you can direct me to a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

With dara in **A1**, use:

```
=TIMEVALUE(substitute(A1," EST",""))
```

and apply suitable formatting.